# How to Link FB Share button to URL inside Application?

Tags: facebook, url, iframe, share

I have multiple share buttons inside my application. When i click them it shares the link of the iframe for example:

```
www.mypage.com/?whatever=whatelse
```

But i need to share this link with the facebook page "around" so the link is in he facebook iframe inside my apllication:

```
www.facebook.com/mypage/app_123456789/?????????????????
```

Is it possible to set some parameters to deeplink inside my application for sharing ?

Right now i just share the index page of my application without any parameters or a specific url inside.

Comment: you'd have to specify the link to share for each share button instance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to use the signed_request variable to store the the page you wanted to share. From what I remember there is an app_data field in this that allows you to store custom values - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/

You'd then have to extract the custom variable from the signed_request->app_data when the page is requested to determine which content to load. You could then obviously share the link to the fb page with the signed_request tacked on. It is still requesting just one page, but kinda simulates deep-linking.